# JSF works only with the .xhtml ending

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets

i start with the programming of a JSF Website. At the moment all files have the .xhtml ending. When i go to http://localhost:8080/myProject/start.jsf everything is all right. But when i rename the file from start.xhtml to start.jsf i became a NoClassDefFound Error.

What is my mistake?

```
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to change the `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` parameter (in web.xml)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jsf</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, this is not advisable - either use `.xhtml` or `.jsp` for your files.
Note that you can use `.jsp` with facelets with no problems (if, for example the auto-complete of your IDE doesn't work for `.xhtml`).

Also note that:

- the faces servlet mapping determines how the jsf pages are referred to from http perspective
- the `DEFAULT_SUFFIX` parameter indicates what's the extension of the files.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to rename the file `start.jsf`? The correct extension of the JSF files are `.xhtml` (but you can modify this default extension, as stated by Bozho).

In fact, to be precise, this extension is defined by [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net) (or JSF 2.0, as it natively integrate Facelets), which is different if you use "basic" JSP files.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to stay with .xhtml because that's the right way to do it, but you can configure it with the javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX context-param in web.xml.

Comment: With the .xhtml extention i can download the Page with the Code. And Eclipse dont make the code completion with .xhtml files